# Erlang Eclipse not responding when try to run

Tags: eclipse, erlang

I am trying to run Erlang compiler from Eclipse but it continuously shows nothing or Eclipse becomes not responding. According to one of these tutorials,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrkhIGzCr3Q

when I press the run button, tt must show me Erlang console window for me to interact with but my Ecllipse with Erlide does not show me anything and sometimes it become not responding. I have tried few possible solutions for the issues including

// including this in eclipse.ini  -Derlide.runtime=/path/to/your/erlang/installation/directory

http://erlide.org/blog/2013/03/10/problems-at-first-start/

// Adding Erlang installation path to environment variables
http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/erlang-getting-started-and-using-eclipse/

// reinstalling erlide with new Eclipse copy

However, I still cannot run Erlang on Eclipse properly. I am happy to explain furthermore about the issue I am having and I hope to receive suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by doing a couple of things

1) reinstalling current Erlide plugin on Eclipse with http://erlide.org/update_nightly/

2) making sure go to

> ```
> run -> run configuration -> runtimes
> ```

and set to "short name"

I hope this helps anyone. Good luck