# Erlang is not returning anything with spawn

Tags: eclipse, shell, erlang, spawn, erlang-shell

I am learning the basics of erlang from a video in [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS60CMWSzMQ&index=12&list=PLJr0bQpUAsMjwKxwHQXEunWQaZ9q5ttuH). And I am stuck at one of the video tutorial. This is the code:

```
say_something(_,0) ->
    io:format("Done ~n");
say_something(Value, Times) ->
    io:format("~s ~n", [Value]),
    say_something(Value, Times-1).

start_concurrency(Value1, Value2) ->
    spawn(easy, say_something, [Value1, 3]),
    spawn(easy, say_something, [Value2, 3]).
```

The `say_something` function is ok:

```
(ErlangProject@Carl-PC)3> easy:say_something("Hello world", 3).
Hello world 
Hello world 
Hello world 
Done 
ok
```

But, when I run `start_concurrency`, I don't know what happens, but I don't get what I am supposed to get, as in here:

```
(ErlangProject@Carl-PC)4> easy:start_concurrency("Hello world", "Really Really").
easy:start_concurrency("Dynamically", "ee").
easy:start_concurrency("dfd", "dfd").
```

It doesn't return anything. I can just type on and on. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: It is working for me when I run in the Erlang shell. I am seeing the phrases print in non-deterministic order and the Pid of the second spawn call display.

Comment: it can work on my erlang shell. you can try `flush()` in your erlang shell.

Comment: Yes, I too can run it in the erlang shell. But before I was running it in the eclipse. Is it a problem with eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this solved the problem:

1. I had to change the `Erlide plugin` location on Eclipse with [this](http://erlide.org/update_nightly/) plugin location.

This was the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135262/erlang-eclipse-not-responding-when-try-to-run) which helped me. Hope it will help others too!

- I tried this in 32 bit eclipse.

Comment: To make it clearer, the fix for this will be available from version 0.28.

Comment: @VladDumitrescu Thanks for adding more info! :)